# Avoid extra copy when creating a tuple from return values in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, tuples, copy, move

I'm trying to create an object that stores a tuple of objects created from a `static` function but when the `tuple` is created, the objects get copied into the `tuple` instead of being placed directly into it, calling the destructor of each object in the `tuple` twice, a behavior I would like to avoid. Is there a way to fix this without having to create custom move/copy constructors for each plugin class?

The code is as follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{
    template<typename PluginT, typename ContainerT, typename TupleT, size_t... Is>
    static PluginT construct_plugin(ContainerT& container, TupleT&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    {
        return PluginT(container, std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleT>(tuple))...);
    }

    template<typename PluginT, typename ContainerT, typename TupleT>
    static PluginT construct_plugin(ContainerT& container, TupleT&& tuple) 
    {
        return construct_plugin<PluginT>(container, std::forward<TupleT>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleT>>::value>{});
    }
}

struct simple_plugin
{
    template<typename ContainerT>
    simple_plugin(ContainerT& container) {}

    ~simple_plugin()
    {
        std::cout << "simple_plugin destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct plugin_with_params
{
    template<typename ContainerT>
    plugin_with_params(ContainerT& container, int argc, char* argv[]) {}

    ~plugin_with_params()
    {
        std::cout << "plugin_with_params destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename... PluginTs>
struct plugin_container
{
    std::tuple<PluginTs...> plugins;

    template<typename... TupleTs>
    plugin_container(TupleTs&&... tuples) :
        plugins(details::construct_plugin<PluginTs>(*this, std::forward<TupleTs>(tuples))...) {}
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    plugin_container<simple_plugin, plugin_with_params> container(std::make_tuple(), std::make_tuple(argc, argv));
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the behaviour in action:
https://godbolt.org/z/bqjv5r88x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the static function it can't work, because elision through the constructor parameter of the `std::tuple` is impossible.

Unfortunately `std::tuple` lacks a `std::piecewise_construct` constructor like `std::pair` has, which could be used to have the action of your `construct_plugin` be performed in-place in the constructor of the tuple/pair.

You can write your own tuple implementation supporting that, or you can add constructor overloads to your plugins that support construction from a tuple in the way that currently your static helper function does, or you can use the conversion function trick described in the other answer.

---

The reason that a *copy* is done rather than a move is only because you declared the destructors and copy constructors. Had you declared none then moves would have been used instead. Defining copy/move constructors can't help you avoid that they are called. The elision is impossible regardless of how the plugin classes are defined.

---

Also, you probably want `std::forward_as_tuple` instead of `std::make_tuple`, since the latter also makes a copy of the individual object before passing on to the plugin constructor, which I don't think is what you want (not that it would matter for the built-in types you are passing around).

Comment: This is a very good and in-depth answer! Thank you for sharing the knowledge about `std::forward_as_tuple` vs `std::make_tuple`. Upon weighing my options, the creation of a `tuple`-like `plugin_collection` class seems like the way to go. Also I should have been more explicit when I said defining custom copy/move constructors. What I meant is accepting the copy behavior and making constructors that won't disrupt the regular behavior of the plugin classes. Again, thank you!

Comment: @AlexandreDeus this answer is incorrect.  You can bypass the copy/move, but.not with all types.  The rest of the answer is correct.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, of course you are right.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct nocopy{
  nocopy(){}
  nocopy(nocopy const&)=delete;
  nocopy(nocopy&&)=delete;
};
struct maker{
  operator nocopy()const{return {};}
};
std::tuple<nocopy,nocopy> t( maker{}, maker{} );
```

this bypasses the copy constructor in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or above.

A similar technique can be used to get arbitrary functions that return an object to work.

The trick is that there isn't a constructor that accepts the `maker` object, then C++ falls back on invoking the converting operator on the `maker`, whose return value can be elided directly into the object.

Prior to 17, this may bypass the copy ctor at runtime but won't compile unless copy (or move) exists (even if the copy/move ctor has side effects). This is because 17 added guaranteed elision; before that it was optional.

Comment: This is a very strange _feature_. Thank you very much for sharing this neat trick, although I would prefer a wider compatibility. Why would this only work with [tag:c++17] and above?

Comment: @AlexandreDeus guarenteed elision.  Prior to 17 the code won't compile.  If copy ctor exists, may be skipped however.