# How to return a tuple of strings without temporary extra copies in C++?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

My question is similar in spirit to [Avoid extra copy when creating a tuple from return values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75760391/avoid-extra-copy-when-creating-a-tuple-from-return-values-in-c), but since I did not understand the answer at all and because I am talking about the standard types (i.e. they already have move constructors) I will ask it anyway.

Let us assume c++20.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

static tuple<string> get_tuple()
{
    string arg = "This is a long string allocated on the heap";
    return { arg };
}

void main()
{
    auto [x] = get_tuple();
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
}
```

Running this code in Visual Studio 2022 debugger shows that the `string` destructor is called twice and both times it deallocates some memory. I.e. none of the cases is that of an empty string.

It is my understanding that with the advent of the move constructor it should be possible to avoid the temporary extra copy.

This is indeed the case when returning the string directly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static string get_tuple()
{
    string arg = "This is a long string allocated on the heap";
    return arg;
}

void main()
{
    auto x = get_tuple();
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
}
```

But it does not work with the `tuple` (nor does it work with the `pair`).

What am I missing? Why it does not work with the `tuple`? Is there a way to exliminate the temporary extra copy while still returning a `tuple` or something like that?

Comment: `return { std::move(arg) };`.  [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5d7977c512be250).

Comment: @MilesBudnek - yes, it works. Could you arrange it as the answer, so I could credit you? If you could also elaborate a bit (not a must), that would be helpful.

Comment: The original version constructs a tuple from the glvalue `arg`. Then `arg` goes out of scope shortly after, but that still doesn't allow moving from it during the tuple initialization. The revised version moves explicitly to avoid the copy. If you initialized the tuple directly from an xvalue (ie, `return { get_value() };`) that would also sidestep the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `std::move` the string into the `tuple`:

```
static std::tuple<std::string> get_tuple()
{
    std::string arg = "This is a long string allocated on the heap";
    return { std::move(arg) };
}
```

[Demo using a non-copyable type](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5d7977c512be250)

---

This is necessary since the automatic conversion to rvalue is only performed on the object returned.  In this case, `arg` is not the object being returned; an anonymous `std::tuple<std::string>` is.  If you want `arg` to be moved, you must explicitly cast it to an rvalue using `std::move`.

---

Note that this does still require the object in the tuple to be move-constructed, but that's usually fine in most cases.  The answer you linked in your question shows how to deal with the case where the object in the tuple can be neither copied nor moved, which is pretty rare.